# Sphere segment differences

Tags: geometry

Huh, you can build a sphere from squares, triangles, hexagons and so on and so forth, but I was wondering... which option is the most viable one?

Well, once again that's a question that differs a lot by preference and so on, but I was thinking more of what is easier to process for a computer.

Like, there will be different amount of segments when the sphere is built from triangles, squares or hexagons.

The idea behind this is to get the shape, which uses the least segments to form a sphere.

Optional: which shape would provide the best connectivity? Like, with squares, you can form topmost points with triangles, all connecting to one point. But probably there are shapes that can provide seamless results, that all the sphere consists of only 1 shape.

Comment: Triangles are used for tessellation of this type. You can form anything from them without any gaps/overlap.

Comment: @Marc B, make it an answer, please. Wouldn't mind giving a check on that one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles are used for tessellation of this type. You can form anything from them without any gaps/overlap.